# How to assign a domain name to listening port on node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a simple app which works on localhost with node.js.

server.js

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

Is it possible to assign a custom url to that port? Exp: localhost:myapp

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can assign a domain name to an ip address, but you can't set one on a port.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but it's a touch convoluted.

First, you'd need something like Apache or NGinx to act as a reverse proxy.  Your app still runs at localhost:8080 or whatever, but NGinx can listen to a given host name and route that traffic to an 'upstream server' which in this case is localhost:8080.  http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Then you'd have to register that domain name either to a DNS server or for just local development, in your /etc/hosts file.  /etc/hosts would be something like this:

```
127.0.0.1   myapp
```

Comment: It is indeed so complex..thnx for the answer anyway!